# Peterson-2 mutual exclusion algorithm

Tags: algorithm, synchronization, operating-system, mutual-exclusion

The contention-free complexity for classic [Peterson-2 algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peterson%27s_algorithm) is 4 (because it performs 4 read/write operations to shared-registers memory)Is there some verion of Peterson-2 algorithm, which requires less accesses to shared-registers memory ?
It is obvious that 1 access is impossible.But what about 2 or 3 accesses?
Thank you

Answer (score 2):

At least three operations per critical section are needed: a write and a read on entry (to declare acquisition of the mutex and verify that the other process has not acquired), a write on exit (to release the mutex). On entry, process `id` in Peterson's algorithm writes the single-writer register `interested[id]` and the multi-writer register `turn`. At the cost of turning a bounded register into one that also holds an unbounded version number, for two processes, there's a simulation of a multi-writer register by two single-writer registers that makes 1 write per write and 1 read per read, allowing the merger of the two writes in Peterson's algorithm.