# Peterson-2 mutual algorithm

Tags: mutex, mutual-exclusion, contention

The contention-free complexity of the Peterson's 2-proccess algorithm is 4 (performs 3 two accesses to shared-registers memory in the entry code and and one in the exit code ) .
How can I modify the Peterson's 2-proccess algorithm so that  its contention-free complexity will be 3?
Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8287936/peterson-2-mutual-exclusion-algorithm

Comment: the algorithm should satisifes deadlock-freedom

Comment: I do not see how this can be done